# I cant seem to return the correct object that I want returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using NodeJS and some JS promises to attempt to use a CMS through a particular web application. I am attempting to fetch some data from the CMS API and am able to console.log() the data and it shows up in the console just fine. Although when I try to return it, it says the object is undefined. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
module.exports = {

    services: async function(){

        fetch(
          'https://graphql.datocms.com/',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              query: `{
                            service {
                                serviceName
                                serviceImg {
                                    url
                                }
                            }
                        }`
            }),
          }
        )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },  
}
```

Like I said, when I do "console.log(res.data)" instead, it says undefined.

```
const records = require('../public/records');

//root route
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render("landing", {serviceRecord: records.services()});
    console.log(records.services());
});
```

Here is my routing portion of code

[function returning object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfhxP.png)

[How I am using it in index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpZJz.png)

Don't worry token variables are read only!

Comment: Your `services` function doesn't `return` anything - only the promise callbacks do. Add another `return` to return the whole promise chain. Alternatively, drop all the `then()` syntax and use `await` instead if you already declared your function as `async`.

Comment: You’re not doing anything with the promise in `services`. The `return res.data;` doesn’t go anywhere. You have an `async` function but never use `await`. You could actually return the promise with `return fetch(`…`)`…`;`, though I’m not familiar with how `res.render` handles this. From the other responses, it seems that that’s exactly how it’s supposed to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Also, please don't show images of code, just copy and paste the relevant pieces of code into the question.

Answer (score -1):

`services` needs to `return` `fetch`. Fetch returns a promise, so handling the promise and response should happen in your route before render is called.

```
module.exports = {
    services: () => fetch( /* your fetch code */)
}

// Then in your routes...
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const resp = await records.services()
    const serviceRecord = await resp.json()
    res.render("landing", { serviceRecord });
});
```

Also, someone mentioned just using await inside of your services function, which is totally doable, too.

```
module.exports = {
    services: async () => {
        const response = await fetch( /* your fetch code */)
        return await response.json()
    }

}

// Then in your routes...
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const serviceRecord = await records.services()
    res.render("landing", { serviceRecord });
});
```